# Look if a file contains specific data

Tags: python, string

im currently learning python and testing different ways to solve a problem, however im currently stuck.

So, I want to look for specific data, and if it exists return it. I'm extracting data from ebay posts in the phone category, and I want my program to be able to extract data from the description.

This is the description my program gives me `iPhone SE 64gb brand new not used unlocked` Another example:

`Selling my phone, used very carefully.`

And I want my program to print this:

```
Model: iPhone SE, Storage: 64GB
```

I tried this:

`storage_types = {8: "8GB", 16: "16GB", 32: "32GB", 64: "64GB", 128: "128GB", 256: "256GB"}`

```
if storage_types in description:
    print("Storage: ", storage_types)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the description always in the form `[model] [storage] [junk]`? Add some more examples if possible.

Comment: No, it's totally random.

Comment: Then you're going to have to write an AI.

Comment: How do I write an AI? Or is it something very advanced that I should shouldn't bother learning right now?

Comment: Note that your attempted solution looks for the **entire dictionary** in the description. It often helps to describe in words the steps to solve a problem without writing overly much about python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to extract the storage data from the description string. It's not very efficient because it uses a double `for` loop, but it's an improvement on your current code. :)

```
descriptions = [
    'iPhone SE 64gb brand new not used unlocked',    
    'Selling my phone, used very carefully.',
]

storage_types = ["8GB", "16GB", "32GB", "64GB", "128GB", "256GB"]

for desc in descriptions:
    for s in storage_types:
        if s in desc.upper():
            break
    else:
        s = None

    print('Description: {!r}, Storage: {}'.format(desc, s))
```

**output**

```
Description: 'iPhone SE 64gb brand new not used unlocked', Storage: 64GB
Description: 'Selling my phone, used very carefully.', Storage: None
```

Note that this technique isn't very robust: it won't cope if there are any spaces between the number and the 'GB' string. One way to handle that is to use a Regular Expression (aka regex).

---

Extracting the model info will be a little harder, because your code will need to cope with lots of variations in how people write that model data in their description.